# java.io.FileNotFoundException: Temp (Access is denied)

Tags: java, command-prompt, temp

I have no idea why this is happening. The purpose of my code is to compare two files, and I got it from my programming book. This is my code:

```
import java.io.*;

class CompFiles {
public static void main(String args[])
{
    int i=0, j=0;

// First make sure that both files have been specified.
if(args.length !=2 ) {
  System.out.println("Usage: CompFiles f1 f2");
  return;
}

// Compare the files.
try
    {
        FileInputStream f1 = new FileInputStream(args[0]);
         FileInputStream f2 = new FileInputStream(args[1]);

  // Check the contents of each file.
  do {
    i = f1.read();
    j = f2.read();
    if(i != j) break;
  } while(i != -1 && j != -1);

  if(i != j)
    System.out.println("Files differ.");
  else
    System.out.println("Files are the same.");
} catch(IOException exc) {
  System.out.println("I/O Error: " + exc);
   }
 }
}
```

I compiled the code like this: `javac CompFiles.java` then the book told me to copy the files to a temp file using this command: `java CompFiles CompFiles.java temp`. The output is `java.io.FileNotFoundExceptions: Temp(Access is dined)`.
 I am not using any IDEs. Thanks for any answers.

Comment: Do you have a second file `temp`?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: You are comparing two files. One file is `CompFiles.java`, since you just compiled it I think you have it. The second file is `temp`. Do you have a second file in your file system called `temp`? Based on your question, my assumption is you do not.

Comment: temp is not a valid file name hence you are getting the error
refer my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure about the book. But to execute your program :

```
java CompFiles a.java b.java
```

should work. Assuming that a.java b.java are TEXT files and are present in the current directory (The directory location from where u r executing this program).

In your case

```
java CompFiles CompFiles.java temp
```

temp could be a folder hence u get this error

Answer (score 0):

Your command would be `java -cp . CompFiles file1 file2`. But your really should use a package. (-cp . asumes you compiled ComFiles.class to your current directory).

The access denied is most likely caused from the fact that you tried to open a directory as a file stream (`.\Temp\`). If your test-fiels are in Temp, you can use `java -cp . CompFiles temp\file1 temp\file2`.

Answer (score 0):

```
I/O Error: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Temp (Access is denied)
```

You are running program as below 
`Java CompFiles CompFiles.java temp`

Here `temp` is seems like directory name rather than a file name.
so, please give a valid file name in the second argument

You can try this
for eg:

```
Java CompFiles CompFiles.java CompFiles.java
```

this will give you **output: Files are the same**

> Why Access is denying?

**you can not read a directory like a normal file**